# Reshape TensorAudio loaded from audioRecord(real-time) in Android to use it as tensorflow lite(tflite) model's input tensor

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, audiorecord

I am trying to feed tflite model with real-time audio data(which is) in Android.

This is the logic of my program:

1. make `AudioRecord` instance
2. make `TensorAudio` object as Android AudioFormat
3. load all audio samples in `audioRecord`(in `Timer()`)
4. make `TensorBuffer` object for input tensor
5. make `TensorBuffer` object for output tensor
6. do `interpreter.run(inputTensorBuffer, outputTensorBuffer)` for inference.

The problem is step 4. In official [Tensorflow web site](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support), it is insturcted that I should get `tensorAudio.getTensorBuffer()`. My tensorflow lite model needs [256, 20] shape input data(which means 256 audio data that has length of 20), but it looks like input data from `AudioRecord` is linear(for example, [5120] shape).

This there any way that I can reshape [5120] data into [256, 20] in TensorAudio or TensorBuffer?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1337
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO)

        textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.output)
        val recorderSpecsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewAudioRecorderSpecs)

        val SAMPLE_RATE = 16000
        //AUDIO_SOURCE = 1
        //CHANNEL_CONFIG = 1
        val MODEL_INPUT_LENGTH = 20 //L: Length of the filters (in samples)
        val MODEL_PATH = "conv_tasnet_39nx_7_float16.tflite"

        val bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT)

        // 1. make AudioRecord instance
        val audioRecord = AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,
            bufferSizeInBytes)

        //2. make TensorAudio object as Android AudioFormat
        val tensorAudio = TensorAudio.create(audioRecord.format, MODEL_INPUT_LENGTH)

        val interpreter = Interpreter(File(MODEL_PATH))

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        //tensor spec for model input/output
        val inputShape = intArrayOf(256, 20)
        val outputShape = intArrayOf(256, 2, 20)

        Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(1, 500) {
            //3. load all audio samples in audioRecord
            tensorAudio.load(audioRecord);

            //4. make TensorBuffer object for input tensor
            // how do I shaped tensor to [256, 20]?
            val tensorBuffer = tensorAudio.getTensorBuffer()
            //val inputTensorBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(inputShape, DataType.FLOAT32)
            val inputTensorBuffer = convertToTensorBuffer(tensorAudio.tensorBuffer)

            //5.make TensorBuffer object for output tensor
            val outputTensorBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(outputShape, DataType.FLOAT32)
            //interpreter.run(input, output);
            interpreter.run(inputTensorBuffer, outputTensorBuffer.buffer)
        }
    }

    private fun convertToTensorBuffer(samples: TensorBuffer): TensorBuffer {
        // Divide the samples into 20 samples each and fill the tensor buffer
        val numFilters = 256
        val numSamplesPerFilter = 20

        val tensorShape = intArrayOf(numFilters, numSamplesPerFilter)
        val tensorBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(tensorShape, DataType.FLOAT32)

        for (i in 0 until numFilters) {
            val startIndex = i * numSamplesPerFilter
            val endIndex = startIndex + numSamplesPerFilter
            //sliceArray not working with TensorBuffer
            val filterSamples = samples.sliceArray(startIndex until endIndex)
            tensorBuffer.loadArray(filterSamples, intArrayOf(i, 0))
        }
        return tensorBuffer
    }
```

I tried to reshape TensorBuffer by slicing array(in `convertToTensorBuffer` method), but TensorBuffer doesn't support `sliceArray` method.